# ASP.NET Authentication sliding expiry time on custom ticket

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am creating my own authentication ticket using the following code:

```
string formsCookieStr = string.Empty;
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,                              // version
            username,                       // user name
            DateTime.Now,                   // issue time
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),    // expires
            false,                          // Persistence
            userRoleData                    // user data
    );
formsCookieStr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie FormsCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, formsCookieStr);
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(FormsCookie);
```

I want the expiration to be a sliding expiration - each time the client sends a request then the expiration should be reset to 30 mins.  However, I'm only creating the ticket when the user first logs in.  Will ASP.NET automatically keep sliding the expiry time for me, or do I need to do something 'manually' to implement the sliding expiration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's configured in the `forms` section of web.config. The way sliding expiration works is that on each request the ASP.NET engine rewrites the authentication cookie by incrementing the timeout:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms 
      loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" 
      timeout="2880" 
      slidingExpiration="true" 
  />
</authentication>
```

Note however that enabling sliding expiration is one of the things considered as bad practice in the [ASP.NET Security Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650037.aspx).

Comment: thanks.  But surely the default when not using custom tickets is sliding expiration, otherwise the user would get logged out regardless of how current their last request was?  I don't observe this behaviour, and the docs say that sliding expiration is the default.  Am I getting sliding expiration by default with my custom ticket? (I have no slidingExpiration setting in web.config)

Comment: "The way sliding expiration works is that on each request the ASP.NET engine rewrites the authentication cookie by incrementing the timeout" ... Not entirely true, because ASP.net only rewrites the authentication ticket if more than half of the timeout value has passed. http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2004/10/11/241080.aspx

Comment: @BrazenTongue - the link is dead as of Feb 2017, would it be possible to provide a replacement?

Comment: "Sliding expiration resets the expiration time for a valid authentication cookie if a request is made and more than half of the timeout interval has elapsed." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration?view=netframework-4.8#remarks