# Forms authentication expires with session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, authentication, cookies

Whenever a user logs into an ASP.NET MVC application I set the Forms auth cookie like this:

```
var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
    1, //version
    user.Email, // user name
    DateTime.Now, //creation
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), //Expiration
    persistanceFlag, //Persistent
    userData);

var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

When inspecting the cookies with say, Firebug I'd expect the cookie's expiration to be 24 hours from now.
Instead Firefox report that the cookie expires with the Session.
I don't get it.

[image: firebug]

How do I control the lifespan of the cookie?

The goal is to not require the user to log in every morning.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275915/asp-net-authentication-sliding-expiry-time-on-custom-ticket

Comment: I believe I'm doing everything described in the linked question, but firebug still report "Session" as the expiration.

Comment: What is the value of `persistanceFlag`?

Comment: I'm setting the persistanceFlag to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was not setting expiration on the actual cookie (authCookie) as well.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-cs#specifying-the-tickets-timeout-value) is that you are correct about the intended behaviour, and that setting `persistanceFlag` to `true` should set the expiry of the cookie to the same value as the expiry of the token.

However, it is worth noting that the token expiry *is* set correctly, even though the cookie expiry doesn't seem to be. That means that once the expiry period has elapsed, although the client will still send the cookie to the server, the server will not accept it as a form of authentication, and the user will have to re-authenticate. In the light of this, I'm not sure that it matters that the cookie doesn't expire when the timeout elapses (even though it does seem like it should).